# Male equivalent of 小三?

Tags: expressions, names

What's the male equivalent of 小三、二奶, etc.?

The closest thing I can think of is 小白脸 but it seems to be missing that certain something...

Comment: I just want to mention this question reminds me a very brainwashing, vulgar, meaningless, piratical-like, WTF song [小白脸](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9wOuTD28rp4).

Comment: "小王" can be used for male as a network neology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proper term would be 情夫:

> 男女两人,一方或双方已有配偶,他们之间发生性爱的行为,男方是女方的情夫

小三 can also be applied to a male as it means the third party in an affair or 第三者.

二公 and 二爺 are informal terms opposite to 二奶.

小白脸 does not necessarily refers to a man who has committed adultery with a married woman. It can also mean the the guy is living off the woman or that the guy has a fair complexion.

Answer (score 0):

"二爷".
Or be more formal, "情夫".

PS: "小三" can also be used for male in theory.